# Is it possible for a lightweight object to fall straight to the bottom of a shallow lake given an initial velocity?

Tags: classical-mechanics, forces

So i am working on this project in which a drone is used to shoot seagrass seeds at a height. The seeds will be inside a small lightweight capsule that has a pointy nose and a tail. So i want to know whether by letting the capsule fall at a sufficient height where the velocity at contact is high enough for the capsule to overcome the water drag force and travel a specific distance? What equations will help me in determining the height necessary? I just need the capsule to touch the seabed..

Comment: is the capsule indestructible? If not, there may not be any way to touch the seabed without making it denser than water

Comment: Realistically speaking, you should make the capsules more dense than water.  While it's been shown that bullets *can* penetrate the water, they don't make it more than a few feet before the initial velocity is spent, at which point they sink because they're more dense than water.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question will require some additional vital information.

Taking into consideration all the other valuable informatin given by previous posters, what is the weight of the delivery capsule; and, what is the depth that it must travel through the water? What is the area of the capsule, and the density of the sea water? You will need that information, to calculate the speed needed upon entry of the water, for your little missile/capsule; and, to determine the height above the water, from which it must be dropped to reach that speed.

The formula for speed of a falling body in air can be found here: http://oregonstate.edu/instruct/mth252h/Bogley/w02/resist.html

You will NOT be able to "overcome the water drag force". You will just have to deal with it via another calculation. The coefficient of drag MUST be figured using the weight, area, of contact, the density of the sea water through which it will travel, BEFORE you can calculate the speed the capsule must obtain, before hitting the water. Calculating the amount of drag the capsule will encounter, on its fall through the water is a bit more involved. It is quite like figuring balistic speed, and the distance it will penetrate a given medium; only without the the encreased temperature figures. Here are some sites, which might help with that:

https: //en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_(physics)

http: //www.math.udel.edu/~rossi/Math512/2005/Team1.pdf

(Remove the extra space, in these last two URLs. Apparently, I haven't been here long enough to have the priviledge of posting more than one website.)